# Able to import object in scala interpreter but not in file

Tags: scala, import, interpreter

I'm doing a set of problems and figured that I would condense common code into a utility file that I could import rather than copy pasting functions each time. So I created a file u.scala:

```
object u
{

val test = 10

def primeFacs(num : Int) : List[Int] = 
{
    ...
}


def allMultCombos(l : List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
{
    ...
}


def allFacs(num : Int) : List[Int] = 
{
    ...
}

def properFacs(num : Int) : List[Int] =
{
    ...
}

}
```

And compiled it with `scalac u.scala`. Then, in a file in the same directory, I tried `import u` as well as `import u._`, but neither can import it. However, when I open the scala interpreter it imports it just fine:

```
r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$ ls
1.scala     12.scala    15.scala    18.scala    20.scala    23.scala    5.scala     7.scala     9.scala
10.scala    13.scala    16.scala    19.scala    21.scala    3.scala     6.scala     8.py        test.scala
11.scala    14.scala    17.scala    2.scala     22.scala    4.scala     67.scala    8.scala     u.scala

r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$ scalac u.scala
r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import u
     | ._
import u._

scala> test
res0: Int = 10

scala> primeFacs(10)
res1: List[Int] = List(5, 2)

scala> :quit
r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$ scala 23.scala
/Users/r/Documents/prog/euler_scala/23.scala:1: error: not found: value u
import u._
       ^
/Users/r/Documents/prog/euler_scala/23.scala:10: error: not found: value allFacs
    val f = allFacs(i)
                ^
two errors found
r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$ ls
1.scala                        17.scala                       3.scala                        9.scala
10.scala                       18.scala                       4.scala                        test.scala
11.scala                       19.scala                       5.scala                        u$$anonfun$1.class
12.scala                       2.scala                        6.scala                        u$$anonfun$properFacs$1.class
13.scala                       20.scala                       67.scala                       u$.class
14.scala                       21.scala                       7.scala                        u.class
15.scala                       22.scala                       8.py                           u.scala
16.scala                       23.scala                       8.scala
r@ANA:~/Documents/prog/euler_scala$
```

Everything is being run from the same directory. What gives?

Comment: Just a guess: the scala interpreter adds the current folder to libpath (or whatever it's called in scala), whereas scalac doesn't. I don't know exactly, because I always use sbt.

Comment: To be clear scalac is working fine. scala run with no file specified (i.e. as a shell) finds the utility class just fine, but scala running a script in the same directory can't find it.

I tried running it as `scala -classpath . 23.scala` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: After a reboot it worked just fine. But if I add anything to the `u` object it is unable to see the new member, even after recompiling `u.scala`. I suppose I can always reboot whenever I add a function to my utilities file, but if anyone knows why this is happening or how to fix it I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Just use sbt. You can even locally publish your libs.